# Term for a person that is "highly influenced by marketing"

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, orthography, obscure-terms

Some people in our lives are more influenced by marketing techniques then others.  What is a term for someone who gives in to the the powers of persuasion issued by the marketeers?

For example, a woman who must buy everything peddled by a Kardashian.  Or a man that must own a new full size truck despite not having professional need for one in order to be a "real man".

Oftentimes I observe people engaging in this behavior to the detriment to their own and their family's finances.

Comment: "A marketer's dream".

Answer (score 5):

***Suggestible***

This word is widely used in works on marketing research.  For example, in [PsychCentral](http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2011/02/15/the-psychology-of-advertising/) there is an article titled *The Psychology of Advertising*, which says:

> Walter Dill Scott published a book on advertising in 1903 called The 
>   Theory and Practice of Advertising. Interestingly, he asserted that 
>   people were highly suggestible and obedient.
>
> Scott wrote “Man has been called the reasoning animal but he could
>   with greater truthfulness be called the creature of suggestion. He is
>   reasonable, but he is to a greater extent suggestible” (Benjamin &
>   Baker, p. 119-120).

Answer (score 3):

[*Gullible*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gullible) comes to my mind: "Easily duped or cheated."  [*Impresssionable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impressionable) could also work: "Easy to influence."

Answer (score 1):

The idiom that comes to mind is to ["be a slave to (something)"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+a+slave+to+(something)).  The meaning given by Free Dictionary is:

> To be unduly influenced by or care too much about something; to spend too much or time or energy on something.

When I've heard it, the "something" in the phrase is most commonly "fashion," and this use fits your everything-peddled-by-a-Kardashian example- such people are slaves to fashion.  The truck owner might be a slave to masculine ideals, perhaps.  I suppose that slaves to marketing, or maybe slaves to a good gimmick, could also work in general.

Of course, my own term for such types is simply [gullible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gullible).

Comment: lol +1 for gullible!

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a phrase.  I will make one up for you.

> A sucker for a good ad campaign.

or if you want something that sounds more negative:

> A sucker for slick advertising

Collins:  3. (slang) a person who cannot resist the attractions of a particular type of person or thing: *he's a sucker for blondes*

Answer (score 0):

***[Victim of marketing](http://moneyning.com/frugality/are-you-a-victim-of-marketing/)***  is an expression used in advertising/marketing contexts:

> - Did you see that new Foot Locker commercial? The timing was perfect, and watching Tyson hand Holyfield his ear was hilarious. So when I went to the mall and saw signs for the “Week of Greatness” sale, the commercial came to my mind — and I almost bought in.
> - The commercial did its job. Fortunately, I stopped before laying down the credit card.

From: moneyning.com